# Tabular Model Measure works on workspace DB but not on Deployed Server

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

Can anybody provide possible reasons why the same measure work on my local/workspace DB, but not a deployed server?

The following measure works (generates a value in a visual) on the workspace db on my local machine, but not on the deployed server:

```
VAR MaxVersion =
CALCULATE (
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'V_fact_OnlineVersion'[Version_Key] ),
'V_DIM_Version'[Version] = [Latest Version (with movement)]
)
VAR MaxStatus =
CALCULATE (
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'V_DIM_RequestStatus'[RequestStatus] ),
FILTER (
ALL ( 'V_fact_OnlineVersion' ),
'V_fact_OnlineVersion'[Request_Key] = 'V_fact_OnlineVersion'[Request_Key]
&& 'V_fact_OnlineVersion'[Version_Key] = MaxVersion
)
)
RETURN
MaxStatus
```

The same measure gives the following error when deployed on the deployed server and hence the visual does not generate:

The error message in Power BI when using the measure from the deployed tabular database:

```
*MdxScript(Model) (186, 59) Calculation error in measure function containsrow does not support comparing values of type text with values of type integer*
```

The error is Visual Studio/Tabular Editor:

```
*Expression: A function 'CALCULATE' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.*
```

I have managed a workaround (which is not ideal) for it to work on the deployed server by changing SELECTEDVALUE to MAX and adding FILTER ( ALL ( ... to the measure

```
VAR MaxVersion =
CALCULATE (
MAX ( 'V_fact_OnlineVersion'[Version_Key] ), FILTER ( ALL ( 'V_DIM_Version'[Version] )
'V_DIM_Version'[Version] = [Latest Version (with movement)]
)
```

Can somebody please explain this to me or suggest a better solution?

I use the above measure in my measure where I calculate closed support tickets:

```
Closed Support tickets: 
SUMX(VALUES('V_fact_OnlineVersion'[Request_Key]),if([Latest Status] in {"Signed Off", "Cancelled", "Suspended" },1,0)
)
```

[Latest Status] being the result of MaxStatus above

I have managed a workaround (which is not ideal) for it to work on the deployed server by changing SELECTEDVALUE to MAX and adding FILTER ( ALL ( ... to the measure

```
VAR MaxVersion =
CALCULATE (
MAX ( 'V_fact_OnlineVersion'[Version_Key] ), FILTER ( ALL ( 'V_DIM_Version'[Version] )
'V_DIM_Version'[Version] = [Latest Version (with movement)]
)
```